# Deciding who has won a hand of Poker in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, evaluation, poker

What would be the best way to compare two (and only two) players hands in Java using the best combination for 5 cards out of 7 cards (texas hold'em)?

If each card is assigned a value or enum then is there an alogirthm that can be used to decide who has the strongest hand?

I imagine you could either do an integer comparison to see who has the highest value hand or use some form of lookup table.

Having a look around there is a hand evaluator called SpecialKPokerEval: http://code.google.com/p/specialkpokereval/

Would this be suitable and painless to implement into an existing project or should I look at doing something from scratch?

EDIT:

How do the hand evaluators that use integer values work?

How does a lookup table work - does each possible hand have a value assigned to it?

Comment: We're here to provide help with specific problems. Unless you define best this question is too subjective.

Comment: You learn by doing. So try to do it yourself rather than using something someone else did.

Comment: It seems to me that there is probably a standard scoring method for poker hands.  Something like 3 digits - high digit for 1,2,3,4 of a kind, straight, flush, straight flush.  Low 2 digits for high card.

Comment: @HotLicks That doesn't work for double pairs since you need to specify both card heights to be able to break ties on the highest value.

Comment: @Khaur - True (the scheme was just off the top of my head and I forgot two pair), but there's most certainly a simple scheme that covers that, and that poker experts would know.

Comment: This is a very real question and it has a definitive answer.  Hadn't the question be closed I would have been able to provide said answer.  There really is no justification for closing this as *"not a real question"*.

Comment: @silverzx: welcome to SO and don't worry... Typically people are not closing real question as *"not a real question"*.  I can't answer seen  that the question is closed but I can tell you that you do both: you *first* use a lookup table (at least if you want speed), once for each hand, and *then* you do a comparison between the two integers you get back.  Note that it's always a tradeoff between speed and memory: the fastest evaluators out there (doing hundreds of millions of evaluation per second) do use quite a lot of memory.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest doing it from scratch as it's a good exercise.  In fact, it's [problem 54](http://projecteuler.net/problem=54) in "Project Euler" and you could look for solutions to that exercise.